# using the docfx.console nuget package on linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, docfx

At the moment I have a visual studio project and I use the docfx.console nuget package to build the documentation, and everything works fine and as expected... on windows. The point is now I want to make a docker image based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1` which is based on a linux image. And compiling in  this docker image running the command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

Gives the following error

```
 > [build 9/9] RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out:
#22 1.080 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.450+ga8dc7f1d34 for .NET Core
#22 1.080 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
#22 1.080
#22 2.852   Restore completed in 215.94 ms for /app/Documentation/Documentation.csproj.
#22 6.299   Documentation -> /app/Documentation/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/Documentation.dll
#22 6.402   /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmpbd72ebbe5e6b49c1b3244f1f50c8b57a.exec.cmd: /root/.nuget/packages/docfx.console/2.48.1/build/../tools/docfx.exe: Exec format error
#22 6.407 /root/.nuget/packages/docfx.console/2.48.1/build/docfx.console.targets(57,5): error MSB3073: The command ""/root/.nuget/packages/docfx.console/2.48.1/build/../tools/docfx.exe" "/app/Documentation/docfx.json" -o "" -l "log.txt" --logLevel "Verbose"" exited with code 2. [/app/Documentation/Documentation.csproj]
```

I already did some prodding around and I believe I have the issue mostly solved. Running `file`  on `console.exe` shows that this is a `PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows`. And these kind of files should not be executed on linux using `sh` but with `mono`. And indeed running:

```
mono docfx.exe "/app/Documentation/docfx.json" -o "" -l "log.txt" --logLevel "Verbose"
```

builds the documentation just fine as expected. At this point of course I have a bunch of workarounds to get the documentation building correctly, just remove `docfx.console` form the csproj and build it manualy from the command line using a docker command.

But the question is, can I also use the nuget package on linux by changing how the docfx.exe command is run by the nuget package? Or is this only possible by actually fixing this in `docfx.console`?

p.s. in case it matters, the version of docfx.console that I am using is the most recent one available at the time of writing, namely 2.48.1

Comment: One way to fix it is apparently by registering .exe as non-native binaries as described on  https://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/

Comment: But this does not working nicely with docker, since loading kernel modules should be loaded on the host, and not in the container. And one does not always have acces to the host.

Comment: There's a dockerhub container that runs it on linux https://hub.docker.com/r/tsgkadot/docker-docfx/dockerfile. I had it working in GitLab CI but had to switch to microsoft's .net image instead for CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the question is, can I also use the nuget package on linux by changing how the docfx.exe command is run by the nuget package? Or is this only possible by actually fixing this in `docfx.console`?

Create script `docfx` that runs `docfx.exe` using Mono, e.g., like this (assuming `docfx.exe` is located in `/opt/docfx/docfx.exe`):

```sh
echo '#!/bin/bash\nmono /opt/docfx/docfx.exe $@' > /usr/bin/docfx && chmod +x /usr/bin/docfx
```

Then, pass MSBuild parameter `BuildDocToolPath` with path to that script, e.g., like this:

```sh
dotnet publish -c Release -o out -p:BuildDocToolPath=/usr/bin/docfx
```

`docfx.console` will than use this path to execute DocFX. I think the property `BuildDocToolPath` isn't documented anywhere, but you can [see it in source code](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/blob/1344ba89cab535f708d8fcabd311c2932c695564/src/nuspec/docfx.console/build/docfx.console.targets#L3).